# LSI Megaraid missing raid1 drive group after replace faulty drive

Tags: raid, storcli

in my server a faulty drive was swapped (E252:0). LSI 9260 controller.
before swap i set the drive to missing, offline and spin down (252:0)
Server was shut down before swap.

After Power On the Raid1 is missing (252:0 and 252:1)
The DID Value for E252:1 didn't change
How i can recover the Raid for 252:1?
Thanks

```
root@rescue ~ # storcli /c0 show all
Generating detailed summary of the adapter, it may take a while to complete.

CLI Version = 007.1316.0000.0000 Mar 12, 2020
Operating system = Linux 5.4.47
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = None


Basics :
======
Controller = 0
Model = LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260-4i
Serial Number = SV15310627
Current Controller Date/Time = 10/06/2020, 13:00:49
Current System Date/time = 10/06/2020, 15:00:50
SAS Address = 500605b0042835f0
PCI Address = 00:02:00:00
Mfg Date = 12/27/11
Rework Date = 00/00/00
Revision No = 61A


Version :
=======
Firmware Package Build = 12.15.0-0239
Firmware Version = 2.130.403-4660
Bios Version = 3.30.02.2_4.16.08.00_0x06060A05
Preboot CLI Version = 04.04-020:#%00009
WebBIOS Version = 6.0-54-e_50-Rel
NVDATA Version = 2.09.03-0058
Boot Block Version = 2.02.00.00-0000
Bootloader Version = 09.250.01.219
Driver Name = megaraid_sas
Driver Version = 07.710.50.00-rc1

.......

Drive Groups = 2

TOPOLOGY :
========

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT     Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID0 Optl  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID0 Optl  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N
 0 0   0   252:2    7   DRIVE Onln  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N
 1 -   -   -        -   RAID0 Optl  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N
 1 0   -   -        -   RAID0 Optl  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N
 1 0   0   252:3    6   DRIVE Onln  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

DG=Disk Group Index|Arr=Array Index|Row=Row Index|EID=Enclosure Device ID
DID=Device ID|Type=Drive Type|Onln=Online|Rbld=Rebuild|Optl=Optimal|Dgrd=Degraded
Pdgd=Partially degraded|Offln=Offline|BT=Background Task Active
PDC=PD Cache|PI=Protection Info|SED=Self Encrypting Drive|Frgn=Foreign
DS3=Dimmer Switch 3|dflt=Default|Msng=Missing|FSpace=Free Space Present
TR=Transport Ready

Virtual Drives = 2

VD LIST :
=======

-------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC     Size Name
-------------------------------------------------------------
0/1   RAID0 Optl  RW     Yes     RWTD  -   ON  2.728 TB
1/2   RAID0 Optl  RW     Yes     RWTD  -   ON  2.728 TB
-------------------------------------------------------------

VD=Virtual Drive| DG=Drive Group|Rec=Recovery
Cac=CacheCade|OfLn=OffLine|Pdgd=Partially Degraded|Dgrd=Degraded
Optl=Optimal||dflt=Default|RO=Read Only|RW=Read Write|HD=Hidden|TRANS=TransportReady|B=Blocked|
Consist=Consistent|R=Read Ahead Always|NR=No Read Ahead|WB=WriteBack|
AWB=Always WriteBack|WT=WriteThrough|C=Cached IO|D=Direct IO|sCC=Scheduled
Check Consistency

Physical Drives = 4

PD LIST :
=======

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                  Sp Type
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    13 UGood -  278.875 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST3300657SS            U  -
252:1    12 UGood -  278.875 GB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST3300657SS            U  -
252:2     7 Onln  0    2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD3000FYYZ-01UL1B2 U  -
252:3     6 Onln  1    2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B TOSHIBA DT01ACA300     U  -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID=Enclosure Device ID|Slt=Slot No.|DID=Device ID|DG=DriveGroup
DHS=Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood=Unconfigured Good|GHS=Global Hotspare
UBad=Unconfigured Bad|Sntze=Sanitize|Onln=Online|Offln=Offline|Intf=Interface
Med=Media Type|SED=Self Encryptive Drive|PI=Protection Info
SeSz=Sector Size|Sp=Spun|U=Up|D=Down|T=Transition|F=Foreign
UGUnsp=UGood Unsupported|UGShld=UGood shielded|HSPShld=Hotspare shielded
CFShld=Configured shielded|Cpybck=CopyBack|CBShld=Copyback Shielded
UBUnsp=UBad Unsupported|Rbld=Rebuild

Enclosures = 1

Enclosure LIST :
==============

--------------------------------------------------------------------
EID State Slots PD PS Fans TSs Alms SIM Port# ProdID VendorSpecific
--------------------------------------------------------------------
252 OK        8  4  0    0   0    0   1 -     SGPIO
--------------------------------------------------------------------

EID=Enclosure Device ID |PD=Physical drive count |PS=Power Supply count|
TSs=Temperature sensor count |Alms=Alarm count |SIM=SIM Count ||ProdID=Product ID


root@rescue ~ # storcli /c0 /fall show
CLI Version = 007.1316.0000.0000 Mar 12, 2020
Operating system = Linux 5.4.47
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Couldn't find any foreign Configuration
```

Comment: Are you sure they didn't switch both drives? was it a RAID 0?

Comment: somehow i gained read access to the 252:1 drive. it was not possible for me to boot from it.
data is now copied to new drive und running again with rebuilt of raid1